# kinetic js image is cropped in memory when dragging

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs

I have applied dragging (built in ability) on my group which consists of image object and 4 anchor objects (shapes).

When I move group all works ok, but when I want to save that image. Image gets cropped as Image(group) is moved away of (0,0) position. If I load image and save it when it is on (0,0) position get full image in file, but if dragged it away from 0,0 than my image gets cropped progressively, when I save it.
I observed what toDataURL() is returning and really further I go from 0,0 string gets shorter from toDataURL()

Please can somebody help me.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you drag the group, you must define the x,y,width,height properties of toDataURL:**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Kr3t2/

```
var url=group.toDataURL({
    x:group.x(),
    y:group.y(),
    width:group.getWidth(),
    height:group.getHeight()
});
```